# Ode-cay Olf-gay

Tags: code-golf, string

Write a program which accepts a sentence into stdin, and writes that sentence to stdout in pig latin.

Here are some test cases which your program should handle:

```
Input:
    Read your script
Output:
    ead-Ray our-yay ipt-scray
```

Hyphenation is mandatory. Note that multiple consonants at the start of the word must all be moved to the end. Capitalization of the output does not matter; `Ead-ray` or `ead-ray` are also valid translations of `Read`

```
Input:
    An utterance is allowed an opening vowel
Output:
    An-way utterance-way is-way allowed-way an-way opening-way owel-vay
```

Words starting with vowels have `-way` appended in their pig latin form (don't forget to handle capital opening vowels)

```
Input:
    sky
    -skyay
```

Words consisting entirely of consonants should have a hyphen prepended, and `ay` appended

Punctuation is undefined; I don't care if leading or trailing punctuation ends up inside the pig latin word.

This is code golf; the shortest program by character count wins. I've written a solution myself which handles all these cases which I shall post as a response.

Comment: And what if there is a language that has a built-in piglatinify function? The Odegolfpay language springs to mind. You should add a clause that penalises the use of libraries like that.

Comment: @MrLister I think it's better to not add a bunch of little restrictions to the puzzle unless it's actually a problem. Besides, an answer in such a language really isn't very interesting and I doubt it would get many upvotes.

Comment: @PeterOlson O-Kay.

Comment: -[151](http://genius.com/Tech-n9ne-caribou-lou-lyrics) point bonus if an input of `caribou lou` gives `aribou-kay, ou-lay, terrible day, you pay the liquor store teller with no hair or toupe`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Perl (53)

```
s/(.*?)([aeiou].*)/$1||=w;print"$2-$1ay "/iefor split
```

Answer (score 4):

### Python, 89

```
import re
print re.sub('-a','-wa',re.sub('(?i)([^aeiou ]*)(\w*)',r'\2-\1ay',raw_input()))
```

Answer (score 4):

### Perl, 41 excluding switches

A simple modification of [Timwi's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8797/ode-cay-olf-gay/8908#8908). Runs with `perl -p`. Does not meet the spec for 'sky', but the original doesn't either.

```
s/(\S*?)([aeiou]\S*)/"$2-".($1||w).ay/ige
```

Answer (score 3):

### Perl (60)

Use `perl -n`. The -n switch is counted (as two characters).

```
s/(.*?)([aeiou].*)/print"$2-$1"."w"x!$1."ay "/iefor split
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Python - <s>122</s> 85 characters

```
import re
print re.sub("-a","-wa",re.sub("([^aeiou ]*)(\w*)",r"\2-\1ay",raw_input()))
```

122 -> 85: Improved use of regexes; running regex on whole sentence rather than individual words, and doing all the processing with regexes rather than a conditional expression. This ended up making it pretty similar to grc's answer

Comment: I would switch to Python 3 and shave off 2 characters :)

Answer (score 2):

**Cojure - 376 characters**

Obviously not winning this one, but figured I'd take a shot at it.

Minified:

```
(defn n [a b] (reduce #(and % %2) (map #(= (.indexOf a %) -1) (map string/lower-case (rest b)))))
(defn t [a] (let [vowels ["a" "e" "i" "o" "u"] x "ay"] (if (> (.indexOf vowels (string/lower-case (first a))) -1) (str a "-way") (if (n vowels a) (str a x) (str (reduce str (rest a)) "-" (first a) x)))))
(defn ay-ya [a] (reduce str (map #(str (t %) " ") (string/split a #" "))))
```

Actual:

```
(defn no-vowel [a b]
    (reduce #(and % %2) (map #(= (.indexOf a %) -1) (map string/lower-case (rest b)))))

(defn transform [text]
  (let [vowels ["a" "e" "i" "o" "u"]]
    (if (> (.indexOf vowels (string/lower-case (first text))) -1)
        (str text "-way")
        (if (no-vowel vowels text)
          (str text "ay")
          (str (reduce str (rest text)) "-" (first text) "ay")))))


(defn ay-ya [text]
    (reduce str
        (map #(str (transform %) " ")  
             (clojure.string/split text #" "))))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org),  <s>78</s>  66 bytes

```perl6
put get.words.map: {samecase S:i/(.*?)(<[aeiou]>.*)|(.*)/$1-{~$0||'w'}ay/, $_}
put get.words.map: {~S:i/(.*?)(<[aeiou]>.*)|(.*)/$1-{~$0||'w'}ay/}
```

( You would use the `samecase` one if you cared about capitalization )

```
$ perl6 -e 'put get.words.map: {~S:i/(.*?)(<[aeiou]>.*)|(.*)/$1-{~$0||"w"}ay/}'
Read your script
ead-Ray our-yay ipt-scray

$ perl6 -e 'put get.words.map: {~S:i/(.*?)(<[aeiou]>.*)|(.*)/$1-{~$0||"w"}ay/}'
An utterance is allowed an opening vowel
An-way utterance-way is-way allowed-way an-way opening-way owel-vay

$ perl6 -e 'put get.words.map: {~S:i/(.*?)(<[aeiou]>.*)|(.*)/$1-{~$0||"w"}ay/}'
sky
-skyay
```

Comment: auto +1 for Perl 6!

Answer (score 1):

### K, 95

```
" "/:{$[&/~x in v:v,_v:"AEIOU";"-",x,"ay";("-"/:|_[;x]0,*&t),$[*t:x in v;"way";"ay"]]}'" "\:0:0
```

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure - 113 chars

```
(clojure.string/replace(read-line)#"([^aeiouAEIOU ]*)(\w*)"(fn[[a c r]](if(=""a)""(str r"-"(if(=""c)\w c)"ay"))))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Ruby 1.9, 68**

```
puts ARGV.map{|w|w[/^([^aeiou]+)(.*)/i]?$2+"-"+$1+"ay":w+"-way"}*" "
```

Comment: I counted 68 characters ...

Answer (score 0):

## C, 134 bytes

```c
char w[99],*p;c;main(l){for(;c^10;c=getchar())scanf("%s",w),p=strpbrk(w,"aeiouAEIOU"),l=p-w,printf("%s-%.*say ",p?p:"",l+!l,l?w:"w");}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Lexurgy](https://www.lexurgy.com/sc), 116 bytes

```bash
p:
([]+)$1 *=>$1 \-way/$ {a,e,i,o,u} _
({b,c,d,f,g,h,j,k,l,m,n,p,q,r,s,t,v,w,x,y,z}+)$1 ([]*)$2 => $2 \- $1 ay/$ _
```

+52 bytes if you want case-insensitive support.